# Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Execution Timeout Expired" when deploying database changes with Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy database changes to a SQL Server using Azure DevOps. The database deployment job has six tasks, as follows:

1. Initialize job
2. Download artifact
3. Drop Publications
4. SQL DB Deploy
5. Restore Publications copy
6. Finalize Job

On step #3 (Drop Publications) i get the following error:

> Error running SQL script: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

I am using the DACPAC deployment type.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Probably something in your code...

Comment: @HoneyBadger can you elaborate? Do you mean the code in the database deployment script?

Comment: I was perhaps being overly snarky. I meant if you don't show any code, we cant tell you what's wrong. You have enough rep to know how to ask a good question. Where are you calling ExecuteNonQuery, and how do you call it?

Comment: You are right, i know how to ask a good question. Azure DevOps was set-up in my organization by somebody else and I am having to troubleshoot this issue now on my own. I am completely new to Azure and kind of grasping in the dark right now. With that said, i was able to find out that the Drop Publications task calls a custom stored procedure in a database. I found the stored procedure in question and looked at it (can't post it here due to too much sensitive information in it) and I don't see calls to "ExecutenonQuery" anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure step 3 is the one that gives the error message? If it (only) calls a procedure, I don't think that's where the error originates. ExecuteNonQuery is a C# thing (other languages as well, I think, but with Azure C# is likely). So I'd look for some script that gets executed, perhaps in step 4.